# tocstyle: make word "Chapter 1" bold in TOC, but not chapter title

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, tocstyle

In the scrreprt class, using the package tocstyle, I would like the word "Chapter 1" to be bold in the TOC, but not the title of the chapter (see image). How do I achieve this? As per default, everything is bold. Using `\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries}` changes the font of the entire TOC entry line.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright, BCOR=1cm, headsepline,chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}

%%---header/footer
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\automark{chapter}
%%--"Chapter #" in lehead, chapter name in rohead
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}%
}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}


\usepackage{lipsum}

%%---add "Chapter #" in TOC before chapter title, only for numbered chapters
\let\oldaddchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
    \ifstr{#1}{}{%
        \oldaddchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}}{%
        \oldaddchaptertocentry{\chapapp{} #1}{#2}%
}}


\usepackage[toctextentriesindented]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
\settocstylefeature{spaceafternumber}{16pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{An interesting title}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\section{A slightly less interesting title}
\lipsum[1-5]

\addchap{Unnumbered chapter}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\section{Section title}
\lipsum[6-15]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that package `tocstyle` is not developed anymore. Therefore you will get warnings.

I would suggest to use commands, options etc. of package `tocbasic`. This package is also part of the KOMA-Script bundle and the KOMA-Script class loads `tocbasic` automatically.

Suggestion without `tocstyle`:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside, openright, BCOR=1cm, headsepline,chapterprefix=true,
  toc=indentunnumbered% <- added
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

%%---header/footer
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\automark{chapter}
%%--"Chapter #" in lehead, chapter name in rohead
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}%
}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}

\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\textbf,
  numsep=16pt,
  dynnumwidth
]{chapter}{chapter}

%%---add "Chapter #" in TOC before chapter title, only for numbered chapters
\let\oldaddchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
    \ifstr{#1}{}{%
        \oldaddchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}}{%
        \oldaddchaptertocentry{\chapapp{} #1}{#2}%
}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\chapternumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\chaptertocdepth}

\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{empty}% if all chapter pages should use page style empty
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{An interesting title}
\newpage
\section{A slightly less interesting title}
\lipsum[1-5]

\addchap{Unnumbered chapter}
\newpage
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[6-15]
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get:

[image]

---

If the page number of the chapter entry should be bold too, you can add

```latex
pagenumberformat=\usekomafont{chapterentry}\textbf
```

to the options of `\DeclareTOCStyleEntry` for chapter.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[twoside, openright, BCOR=1cm, headsepline,chapterprefix=true,
  toc=indentunnumbered% <- added
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text

%%---header/footer
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\automark{chapter}
%%--"Chapter #" in lehead, chapter name in rohead
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}%
}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}

\addtokomafont{chapterentry}{\mdseries}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\textbf,
  pagenumberformat=\usekomafont{chapterentry}\textbf,
  dynnumwidth
]{chapter}{chapter}

%%---add "Chapter #" in TOC before chapter title, only for numbered chapters
\let\oldaddchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
    \ifstr{#1}{}{%
        \oldaddchaptertocentry{#1}{#2}}{%
        \oldaddchaptertocentry{\chapapp{} #1}{#2}%
}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\chapternumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\chaptertocdepth}

\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{empty}% if all chapter pages should use page style empty
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{An interesting title}
\newpage
\section{A slightly less interesting title}
\lipsum[1-5]

\addchap{Unnumbered chapter}
\newpage
\section{Section title}
\lipsum[6-15]
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way by adding inside `\textnormal` the second argument of your defined command:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openright, BCOR=1cm, headsepline,chapterprefix=true]{scrreprt}

%%---header/footer
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\automark{chapter}
%%--"Chapter #" in lehead, chapter name in rohead
\renewcommand*\chaptermark[1]{%
    \markboth{\ifnumbered{chapter}{\chaptermarkformat}{}}{#1}%
}

\AfterTOCHead[toc]{\markboth{}{\contentsname}}


\usepackage{lipsum}

%%---add "Chapter #" in TOC before chapter title, only for numbered chapters
\let\oldaddchaptertocentry\addchaptertocentry
\renewcommand{\addchaptertocentry}[2]{%
    \ifstr{#1}{}{%
        \oldaddchaptertocentry{#1}{\textnormal{#2}}}{%
        \oldaddchaptertocentry{\chapapp{} #1}{\textnormal{#2}}%
}}


\usepackage[toctextentriesindented]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{KOMAlike}
\settocstylefeature{spaceafternumber}{16pt}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{An interesting title}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\section{A slightly less interesting title}
\lipsum[1-5]

\addchap{Unnumbered chapter}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

\section{Section title}
\lipsum[6-15]

\end{document}
```

[image]